# Google Map File

Tags: android, google-maps

How to store Google map file into Sqlite database?

Comment: What do you want to store? The images? I don't think you are allowed to do that.

Comment: Am doing one app. in that user will visit some places, am marking those places using draw-path..now i want to store this for later use..

Comment: So you want to store the position (coordinates) of the places?

Comment: no.i want to save the map file..like when the phone is offline also user can see his visiting places.

Comment: what is a google map file? are you trying to say the gpx or kml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps has no real support for caching. There is no public API to get the map data in its entirety and cache it up for later usage. Thus, you're not really going to be able to view that data on a map if the user exits the map activity and goes offline. You can of course save placemarks and such to KML or a database (maybe even with a jpg snapshot of the map), but that doesn't sound like what you want.

Google Earth **does** have support for caching, however the cache is very small (I don't know the max size off the top of my head). Furthermore, you can't push any data through Google Earth on the phone since it has no public API. If you happen to have a Google Earth Enterprise server sitting around, you can point the phone at your server and use network links to serve data up to the globe with some evil black magic trickery.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I think you want to store only the co-ordinates into the database! You can get it by exploiting GPS. I am not a seasoned programmer, but trying to see myself, if I get an example answer soon, i will comeback :)